# Spring boot get form input always null

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist

I try to get an input form with model `@requestbody` in spring boot controller. The parameter is dynamic, there will be more than 1 input with the same name. So i assume to using array as the part of the name.

When `setting.getProduct()` in controller. The return is always null while debugging. And it's looping forever. Is there any issue there?

I expect, it will loop twice and get the correct value

**MODEL**

```
public class LenderSetting {
    String product, limit,nominal;

    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitRuleSetting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String dopostrule(@RequestBody List<LenderSetting> lendersetting,HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest req) {
        token.regenToken(session);
        JSONArray abc = new JSONArray();
    
        for (LenderSetting setting : lendersetting) {
            JSONObject hoho = new JSONObject();
            String product = setting.getProduct();
            hoho.put("product",product);
            abc.put(hoho);
            
        }
        return "";
        
    }
```

**HTML FORM**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Product</label>
        <select name="lendersetting[0].product" class="form-control">
            <option value="A02">A02</option>
            <option value="A08">A08</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Product</label>
        <select name="lendersetting[1].product" class="form-control">
            <option value="A02">A02</option>
            <option value="A08">A08</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

**FORM AJAX**

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($("#formInput").serializeArray()));
                    $.ajax({
                        type : "POST",
                        url : "${url}/submitRuleSetting",
                        data: JSON.stringify($("#formInput").serializeArray()),
                          contentType: "application/json", header to JSON
                          dataType: "json", 
                          cache: false,
                        //... REST
});
```

**Console Result**

```
{"name":"lendersetting[0].product","value":"A02"},{"name":"lendersetting[1].product","value":"A02"},
```

Comment: I would recommend you to wrap your list `lendersetting` into an object that contains this list firstly. Next what you need, regarding to the first step, convert your json into an object that contains an array `{     "foos" : [{         "prop1":"value1",         "prop2":"value2"     }, {         "prop1":"value3",          "prop2":"value4"     }] }`.